# Visiontek modem in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, modem

Within a few days my broadband connection will be cut.Then the only way I can connect is to use a usb modem(Visiontek 82GH HSUPA).The problem is I cannot use the modem in an ordinary account and has to login using a root account to use it.So is there some way to use an ordinary account to use the modem.Using gksudo or sudo does'nt help.Please this is urgent.Thanks in advance.I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
Please suggest some way to get temporary root rights or something else.
For those who do'nt know how visiontek works,I will try to explain it the best I can.
In windows Visiontek can be run by just inserting it and then installing a program.But in Linux its more complicated.You have to copy a folder from the modem to the usr folder.And in that you should first run the install script and dialup script both with root rights,all while inserting the modem.When I run the dialup script in an ordinary acount it says the usb modem is not ejected even when it is while in the root account it runs okay(You have to eject the modem before dialup for it to work.This will open the built-in memory card reader.)

Answer (score 0):

sudo will give you root rights, but not the root environment.

$ sudo su -

this will give you the root environment too, assuming this is the issue.
if it is just root rights for the application you are trying to run, assuming the tool is called modem-tool:

$ sudo chown root:root modem-tool
$ sudo chmod u+s modem-tool

this will make the program modem-tool run with root priviliges

(the commands you need to type are behind the $ sign)

Comment: So how should I write it in the terminal.Sorry there are a lot of commands here.I did'nt understand in which order to type it.

Comment: It says operation not permitted.